# How to solve recurrence relations - expected value

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm solving a question where the recurrence relation I created is as follows:

$$\begin{cases}E_0=0\\E_1=2\\E_n = 2E_{n-1} + 2&\text{for }n>1\end{cases}$$

How can I create a closed form solution for this?

Comment: Plenty of methods for this sort of equation; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$E_n+2=2E_{n-1}+4=2(E_{n-1}+2).$$

As the terms are each time doubled, it should be obvious that the solution is

$$E_n+2=2^n(E_0+2)$$

> $$E_n=2^{n+1}-2.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is an [arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) and has the solution
$$a_n=2(2^n-1)$$

Comment: Though I'm not sure what expected value has to do with this.

Comment: The question definitely lacks that context but e.g. recurrence relations often yield expected hitting times of states in Markov chain theory.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: difference equations.

1. Get rid of the constant, set $F_{n+1} = E_{n+1} - E_n = \Delta E_{n+1}$:
   $$
   E_{n+1} = 2 E_{n} + 1\\
   E_{n} = 2E_{n-1} + 1\\
   F_{n+1} = 2F_n
   $$
2. Write down the recurrence until you arrive at $F_1$.
   $$
   F_{n+1} = 2^{n}F_1 = 2^{n+1}
   $$

3. Telescopic summation on LHS and RHS:
   $$
   E_{n+1} = 2^{n+1} + 2^{n} + \ldots 2 = 2^{n+2} - 2  = 2(2^{n+1}-1)
   $$